# CallKit Call hasConnected always returning true

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, voip, callkit

I am working on a VOIP app and implementing CallKit on iOS.

From this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcall/1649013-hasconnected?language=objc

> A call is considered connected when both caller and callee can start
> communicating.

What does this mean here? Does it mean that a WebRTC or some other audio/video stream must be started in order for it to return true? or does it mean that if user presses the accept call button it is considered connected?

I have the following code to check status of the call and it is always returning true or whatever i give in resolve:

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];
  
    BOOL _mybool = false;
  
    for(CXCall *call in callObserver.calls){
        
        if([call.UUID isEqual:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidString]] && !call.hasConnected){
         _mybool = true;
          resolve(@"true");
        }
    }
  
    if(!_mybool){
      reject(false, false, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are checking the call state in the wrong place. This is creating a problem in your execution.

You have to first setup callobserver with call it. which you have done correctly. But one flag is required didDetectOutgoingCall

```
func setupCallObserverWithCallKit() {
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            didDetectOutgoingCall = false
            if callObserver == nil {
                callObserver = CXCallObserver()
                callObserver!.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

and then inside callObserver write your logic.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        
        if call.isOutgoing && !didDetectOutgoingCall {
            didDetectOutgoingCall = true
            // "Call button pressed"
        }
        
        if call.hasEnded   == true && call.isOutgoing == false || // incoming end
            call.hasEnded   == true && call.isOutgoing == true {   // outgoing end
            // Disconnected

        }
        
        if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
            // "CXCallObserver : Dialing"
         
           //**Write your logic written in for loop here**

        }
        
        if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
            // "CXCallObserver: Incoming"
        }
        
        if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {
            // "CXCallObserver: Connected")
        }
    }
```

Note: Though this code is in swift language, it is easily understandable and easily convertible to objective-c

Answer (score 0):

```
//init
if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    self.callObserver = [CXCallObserver new];
    [self.callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
}
```

and implement a delegate method - CXCallObserverDelegate

```
#pragma mark - CXCallObserverDelegate
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    //what you need))
    //call.isOutgoing
    //call.hasConnected
    //call.hasEnded
    //call.onHold 
    //call.hasEnded
}
```

Comment: if you need use callKit before iOS 10 - look CTCallCenter.h

Comment: Can you please tell what is wrong in my code? and I am only targeting people above iOS 10 right now